# How to include Facebook Messenger and Instagram in the default share dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-messenger

I am using an activity view controller for sharing in my app. All the apps are visible in share but Facebook Messenger and Instagram are not there. I also tapped on the more button but these two apps are not there.

Comment: What kind of data to you pass to the UIActivityViewController ?
Could you give us the code that does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide code for including third-party apps in the default `UIActivityViewController` share dialog. If the app is downloaded on the device, the option will appear.

Comment: but my app is not published it is under development. So on development mode there is way to get Facebook messenger on activity view controller